# data = JSON.parse(data); syntax error unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

I have a problem with my page. It works on localhost (WebServ). On my vps (Debian 8) it not work.

You can look: http://www.csgobeton.pl/withdraw.

When you do recaptcha it says "syntax error unexpected end of input".

In the console I can see there is a problem at line "data = JSON.parse(data);".

Please help me.

```
function loadLeft(opts) {

  inlineAlert("", "Loading your inventory - please wait...");
  var DIV = "<div class='placeholder matched' data-name='{0}' data-pos='{1}' 
  data - price = '{2}'
  data - bot = '{3}' > ";
  DIV += "<div class='slot {13}' data-view='{15}' data-name='{4}' data-
  pos = '{5}'
  data - price = '{6}'
  data - bot = '{7}'
  data - id = '{8}'
  style = 'background-
  image: url(\"{9}\")'>"; DIV += "<div class='name'>{10}</div>"; DIV +=
    "<div class='price {11}'>{12}</div>"; DIV +=
    "<div class='bot'>{14}</div>"; DIV += "</div></div>";
    var IMG = "{0}/{1}fx{2}f";
    var url = "";
    if (DEPOSIT) {
      url = "/get_inv?" + opts;
    } else {
      var g = grecaptcha.getResponse();
      url = "http://www.csgobeton.pl/get_bank_safe?g-recaptcha-response=" + g;
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: url,

      success: function (data) {
        $("#inlineAlert").html("data");
        try {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          if (data.success) {
            console.log(data);

            $("#left .reals").empty();
            $("#right .reals").empty();
            $("#right .bricks").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#avail").html(formatNum(data.balance));
            var count = data.items.length;
            var eleA = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              var item = data.items[i];
              var url = IMG.format(item.img, 110, 50);
              var price_class = "ball-1";
              if (DEPOSIT) {
                price_class = "ball-0";
              }
              var slot_class = "";
              var price_content = item.price;
              if (price_content == 0) {
                price_content = item.reject;
                slot_class = "reject";
              } else {
                price_content = formatNum(price_content);
              }
              bot = 0;
              if (item.botid) {
                bot = item.botid;
              }
              var botLabel = "";
              if (!DEPOSIT) {

                botLabel = "Bot " + bot;
              }
              var ele = DIV.format(item.name, i, item.price, bot,
                item.name, i, item.price, bot, item.assetid, url, item.name,
                price_class,
                price_content, slot_class, botLabel, item.view);
              eleA.push(ele);
            }
            $("#left_number").html(count);

            document.getElementById("left").getElementsByClassName(
              "reals")[0].innerHTML = eleA.join('');
            addPadding("#left", 6);
            if (data.fromcache) {
              inlineAlert("success", "Loaded " + count + " items from 
                cache - < a href = \
                "javascript:loadLeft('nocache')\">reload inventory</a>"
              );
            } else {
              inlineAlert("success", "Loaded " + count + " items.");
            }
          } else {
            inlineAlert("error", data.error);
            if (data.count > 0) {
              cmd();
            }
          }
          if (data.tid) {
            showPending(data);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          inlineAlert("error", "Javascript error22: " + err);
          console.log(err.stack);
        }
      },
      error: function (err) {
        inlineAlert("error", "AJAX error: " + err.statusText);
      },
    });
  }
```

`index.php` is:

```
case 'get_bank_safe':
    if(!$user) exit(json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'error'=>'You must 
login to access the widthdraw.')));
    $g = curl('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Le-
6R8TAAAAAAjgt_wfQMOUCMxCCAWs-iFlP9T-&response='.$_GET['g-recaptcha-response']);

$g = json_decode($g, true);
    if($g['success'] == true) {
        $array =array('balance'=>$user['balance'],'error'=>'none','items'=>array(),'success'=>true);
        mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
            $sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `status` = 1');
        $prices = file_get_contents('prices.txt');
        $prices = json_decode($prices, true);
        while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
            $array['items'][] = 
array('botid'=>$row['botid'],'img'=>'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'.$row['img'],'name'=>$row['market_hash_name'],'ass
etid'=>$row['id'],'price'=>$prices['response']['items']
[$row['market_hash_name']]['value']*10,'reject'=>'unknown items');
        }
        exit(json_encode($array));
    }
    break;
```

The result of `get_safe_bank` is:

```
{"balance":"0","error":"none","items":    [{"botid":"1","img":"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFAuhqSaKWtEu43mxtbbk6b1a77Twm4Iu8Yl3bCU9Imii1Xt80M5MmD7JZjVLFH-6VnQJQ","name":"Chroma 2 Case","assetid":"8","price":0,"reject":"unknown items"},{"botid":"1","img":"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpoo6m1FBRp3_bGcjhQ09ulq5WYh8jiPLfFl2xU18h0juDU-MKljgLjqRVuaj-gLIKUdQdtMgvS-VK_wrvpgZ7quM_Im3Qw6Cdz4CzZgVXp1o7eGVz_","name":"USP-S | Lead Conduit (Well-Worn)","assetid":"26","price":0,"reject":"unknown items"}],"success":true}{"balance":"0","error":"none","items":[{"botid":"1","img":"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFAuhqSaKWtEu43mxtbbk6b1a77Twm4Iu8Yl3bCU9Imii1Xt80M5MmD7JZjVLFH-6VnQJQ","name":"Chroma 2 Case","assetid":"8","price":0,"reject":"unknown items"},{"botid":"1","img":"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpoo6m1FBRp3_bGcjhQ09ulq5WYh8jiPLfFl2xU18h0juDU-MKljgLjqRVuaj-gLIKUdQdtMgvS-VK_wrvpgZ7quM_Im3Qw6Cdz4CzZgVXp1o7eGVz_","name":"USP-S | Lead Conduit (Well-Worn)","assetid":"26","price":0,"reject":"unknown items"}],"success":true}
```

When I paste it instead `data = JSON.parse(data);` `data` it works correctly.

Comment: And when you `console.log(data)` immediately in the success function, what do you get?

Comment: **minimal** example...

Comment: maybe already parsed by jQuery Ajax... try removing this line `data = JSON.parse(data);`  and check

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen when we have success function in table can see bots' items (from MySQL loading)

Comment: @MuthuKumaran i was remove this line and got `undefined`

Comment: @Jonasw okey, that site is an template (.tpl) who loading index.php (case withdraw) and next to when we done good recaptcha `if($g['success'] == true)` site load items from database `$array =array('balance'=>$user['balance'],'error'=>'none','items'=>array(),'success'=>true);` and check their value in prices.txt. Now this information `{"balance":"0","error"......}` is send to offers.js but something went wrong because browser console shows error in line `data = JSON.parse(data);`. Coding at the server is UTF8 `locale LANG=en_US.UTF8` and everything else too.

Comment: It works when in offers.js I paste `data = JSON.parse('{"balance":"0","error":"none","items":[{"botid":"1","img":"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlW[...]JQ","name":"Chroma 2 Case","assetid":"8","price":"0","reject":"unknown items"}');` so I dont know why..